# Using jquery.validation equalTo( other ) to ensure "Sunday" is the inputted value

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

RE: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

I am setting up a simple contact form and want to use a "quiz" as a simple SPAM protection.

I am therefore asking the question, "What day comes after Saturday?".

To be able to proceed with form submission, I need to work out how to use the "equalTo" method to check if "Sunday" has been inputted by the user before proceeding.

Can anyone help me out with this? I'm not sure what to do. I already have the class="required" set on that input field, but not sure what other class I need to add to get this all working?

Comment: it can be done by taking the val by just ('#idofdiv').val() but make sure your method wont work on the external script for that you need to change every time the day here "What day comes after Saturday?".

Comment: You can just do if($('#inputId').val() == 'Sunday'){}

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo#other

```
$(".selector").validate({
   rules: {
       userResponse: { 
           required: true, 
           equalTo: 'Sunday'
       }
   }
})​;​
```